# SQL Server error "Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement."

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having an issue when running queries or stored procedures. Every time I run a query I get the following error:

> Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement.

If I remove the `WITH NOLOCK` command, I get a different error:

> Msg 824, Level 24, State 2, Line 1
>
> SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect pageid (expected 1:19818941; actual 1:19818957). It occurred during a read of page (1:19818941) in database ID 9 at offset 0x000025cd37a000 in file 'E:\SQLDATA\MSCRM.mdf'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

What should I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Sounds like your database might be corrupt.

Comment: I suppose you should run [DBCC CHECKDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx)...

Comment: I run DBCC CHECKDB  then what?

Comment: Depends on what additional information you receive. If you're expecting an easy answer, start browsing [Paul Randal's blog posts on the topic](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/category/checkdb-from-every-angle/).

Comment: Also did you check the SQL Server error log or the server's event log for additional information, as the error message suggests?

Comment: You restore the database from a know good backup and then you re-do any lost transaction.

Answer (score 8):

First, obviously, try `DBCC CHECKDB`.

If that cannot resolve the issue, you may need to restore from a backup and then manually copy over the most recent changes. Hopefully you have been doing nightly backups... ?

Comment: for me below link works, will help  someone : https://www.sqlshack.com/fixing-error-601-could-not-continue-scan-with-nolock-due-to-data-movement/

Answer (score 0):

If the error is prefixed with any object (Proc, trigger, function), then you can just drop and create the object again or alter it if possible.