# Improving the performance of an SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table containing around 50,000,000 rows and I need to run the following two queries on it:

```
SELECT  Count(*) AS Total
FROM    TableName WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE   Col1 = 'xxx' AND Col2 = 'yyy'
```

then

```
SELECT  TOP 1   Col3
FROM            TableName WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE           Col1 = 'xxx' AND Col2 = 'yyy'
ORDER BY        TableNameId DESC
```

The table has the following structure:

```
dbo.TableName
TableNameId  int PK
Col1         varchar(12)
Col2         varchar(256)
Col3         int
Timestamp    datetime
```

As well as running queries on it, there are loads of inserts every second going into the table hence the NOLOCK.  I've tried creating the following index:

```
NONCLUSTERED INDEX (Col1, Col2) INCLUDE (TableNameId, Col3)
```

I need these queries to return results as quick as possible (1 second max).  At this stage, I have the ability to restructure the table as the data isn't live yet, and I can also get rid of the Timestamp field if I need to.

Comment: Are the values for `Col1` and `Col2` you query against constant? i.e. always `'xxx' and 'yyy'`. In what execution plan did your queries result with that index that you already tried?

Comment: How long are the queries running now?  How accurate does your count need to be?

Comment: no, it's not always xxx and yyy

Answer (score 0):

Firstly - include `TableNameID` in your index and not as included column, then you can specify `descending` in the index order.

That should speed up things regarding your `TOP 1 ... ORDER BY TableNameId DESC`

Secondly - check up on how much time is I/O for example (SET STATISTICS IO ON) and how much is CPU (SET STATISTICS TIME ON). 
If it is I/O there's not much you can do because you do have to move through a lot of data.

Comment: I had this at first, then SQL management studio suggested the index I've used

Comment: With DESC as sort order in the index? If so - show us the query plan.

Comment: Yes, it could make a difference

Comment: thanks I need to drop and create the table again to reindex it then add the 50m rows, then I'll let you know if it worked..

Comment: try it out on a test database/table first, before running it on production. Also take a look at the query plan to determine the order that SQL Server would like the columns just to help it as much as possible

Comment: it's currently adding all the data now, however when I ran the queries with stats on, I got the following: "Table 'TableName'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52764/discussion-between-lisburnite-and-allan-s-hansen)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a very fast estimate of how many rows are in the table, try quering [sys.dm_db_partition_stats](https://www.google.com/search?q=sys.dm_db_partition_stats&oq=sys.dm_db_partition_stats&aqs=chrome..69i57.439j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8):

```
-- Report how many rows are in each table
SELECT o.name as [Table Name], ddps.row_count 
FROM sys.indexes (nolock) AS i 
 INNER JOIN sys.objects (nolock) AS o ON i.OBJECT_ID = o.OBJECT_ID 
 INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats (nolock) AS ddps ON i.OBJECT_ID = ddps.OBJECT_ID 
 AND i.index_id = ddps.index_id 
WHERE i.index_id < 2 
 AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0   -- Remove to include system objects 
 AND ddps.row_count > 0
ORDER BY ddps.row_count DESC
```

If you have multiple partitions, this may not work.  You might need to get the `SUM` of the `row_count`.

However, if you need an accurate count, you will need to count the rows, and this will take a while.  Also, you may get the error ["Could not continue scan with NOLOCK due to data movement."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879720/sql-server-error-could-not-continue-scan-with-nolock-due-to-data-movement)

You didn't mention how long your indexed query is running.  The index and your query look fine to me.